# Need a price quote engine

Tags: 7, ubercart

Folks, I need a module that will give me the ability to collect service requests from anonymous users and will return to them an estimated price, so a quoting engine basically.  I need the information they submit to also be summarized and sent in an email to a sales rep.

I know about Ubercart, but it seems to be overkill for what we need.  Does anyone have experience with it and can vouch for it as far as this problem goes?

EDIT: Further elaboration on collecting service requests.  The requestee selects a few services that they require, and in what quantity, and this request is forwarded to a sales rep who then prices out the request and contacts the requestee via email with a price quote.  Really I see this as a one way mechanism where requests are just submitted, and then the rest of the conversation is carried out either over the phone or via email.

Comment: Sounds like this could be accomplished through a combination of rules and form_api or webform, but it's difficult to know without more detail.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "collect service requests"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ubercart in this way before and it does give you some nice free functionality, for example you can mix non quotable items in your database and have Conditional Actions (Rules) that look to see if you need to make this a quote only type request. Once it's in there, the order can have it's status changed so that the customer can see how it's progressing and you can define new/different order states to correspond further to your workflow.

Having said all that, a D7 install I would probably start on commerce rather than Ubercart :)

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/commerce is that what you're referring to with 'commerce'?  If so, why do you recommend this over Ubercart?

Comment: Yes that is the project I am referring to. If I have the choice I'll use Commerce as it is some of the core developers from Ubercart who are creating a solution from the ground up to take full advantage of the new features (field, everything is a view) of Drupal 7. Ubercart, while being maintained is a port and will have many of the limitations of the D6 version of Ubercart.

Comment: Nice, definitely going to mess around with this.  Seems like it's the future, and if it's the from the same devs as Ubercart, seems like a win to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's much more framework like than Ubercart, so if you get into it, grab the Kickstart package. Another nice thing is the differentiation between product and product displays, which sounds like some work at first, but makes amazing sense once you get into it.

Answer (score 1):

*Receiving requests*

With [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform), you can create forms that allow you, or your site-admins, to create and maintain the form that site-visitors will fill out. When the form gets submitted, you can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to send this information on as an e-mail. The module [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules), provides the bridge between the two modules, allowing Rules to react to webform events.

*Answering requests*

Just turn the whole process around. Again, use webform to create a form for the request reciever to fill out. When this form gets submitted, send a mail to the requestee with the reply.

*Custom work*

You will most likely need to do some amount of custom coding to make this whole thing work. For example, in the mail to the sales rep, a link must be autogenerated to a form that gets prefilled with the requestee's e-mail. Auto-filling the form is likely best done as a hook_form_alter. There is a lenghty [Rules video series](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework) that you can view to learn more about how to work with Rules and how to extend it to do what you need.

Comment: Seems promising.  I'll look into this tomorrow.  Cheers mate.